# Mongodb, $sum with condition

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Documents:

```
[
  {
    name: 'abc'
    length: 25,
    area: 10
  },
  {
    name: 'abc',
    length: 5
  }
]
```

Output after aggregate query:

```
[
  {
     count: 2,
     summarizedLength: 30,
     summarizedArea: null,
     _id: {
       name: 'abc'
     }
  }
]
```

The `length` and `area` should summarized. But only if all documents have the `area` or `length` property.

So if any `length` property is missing by the grouped properties, the `summarizedLength` value should be `null/undefined/not exisitng`, and same with `area`.

I tried this:

```
let query = mongoose.model('mycollection').aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          name: $name
        },
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        },
        summarizedLength: { $sum: "$length" },
        summarizedArea: { $sum: "$area" },
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Problem is, I need to cancel the `$sum` if any property is missing. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Mongo documentation [$sum behavior](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#non-numeric-or-non-existent-fields)

> If used on a field that contains both numeric and non-numeric values,
>   $sum ignores the non-numeric values and returns the sum of the numeric
>   values.
>
> If used on a field that does not exist in any document in the
>   collection, $sum returns 0 for that field.
>
> If all operands are non-numeric, $sum returns 0.

we can `$push` all area and length to array, and compare `count` with the length of array

db.n.aggregate(

```
    [ 
        {
            $group: {
                _id: { name: "$name" }, 
                count: { $sum: 1 }, 
                area : {$push : "$area"}, 
                length : {$push : "$length"} } 
        },
        {
            $project:{
                _id: "$_id",
                count: "$count",
                summarizedLength: { $cond : [ {$eq : [ "$count", {$size : "$length"} ]} , { $sum : ["$length"] }, "not all numbers" ] },
                summarizedArea: { $cond : [ {$eq : [ "$count", {$size : "$area"} ]} , { $sum : ["$area"] }, "not all numbers" ] },
            }
        }
    ] 
)
```

or, we can count the number of `defined` length and area, along with total `count`, if counts matching then all numbers else some undefined.

To strictly check the type, in case if area and length may contain non numeric data, instead of `undefined` we can do `$type` check

```
db.n.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group: {
                _id: { name: "$name" },
                count: { $sum: 1 },
                areaCount : { $sum : { $cond : [ {$eq : [ "$area", undefined ]} , 0, 1 ] } },
                lengthCount : { $sum : { $cond : [ {$eq : [ "$length", undefined ]} , 0, 1 ] } },
                summarizedLength: { $sum: "$length"  },
                summarizedArea: { $sum: "$area"  }
            }
        },
        {
            $project : {
                _id : "$_id",
                count: "$count",
                summarizedLength: { $cond : [ {$eq : [ "$count", "$lengthCount" ]} , "$summarizedLength", "not all numbers" ] },
                summarizedArea: { $cond : [ {$eq : [ "$count", "$areaCount" ]} , "$summarizedArea", "not all numbers" ] },
            }
        }
    ]
).pretty()
```

output

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "abc"
    },
    "count" : 2,
    "summarizedLength" : 30,
    "summarizedArea" : "not all numbers"
}
```